# jboss - how to automate retrying deployment of war file

Tags: jboss7.x

When running jboss 7.1 as a windows service (or not), it occasionally takes more than one try to successfully deploy a war file.  This is not a problem when starting jboss manually since restarts are easy.  However, when jboss runs as a windows service and it is restarted automatically (due to a windows patch), jboss itself may launch, but the war may not.

Is there any way to cause jboss to retry deploying the war after it fails the first time - for example, by changing a setting in standalone.xml?

Comment: Does it print an exception on why it did not deploy? It seems odd to me that it would take more than one try to deploy an application.

Comment: There is a "did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period (60 seconds)".

Comment: Prior to that there is a message JBAS015870 - "Deploy of deployment ... was rolled back with failure message Operation Cancelled"

Comment: Uh, that's odd too. How are you deploying? Feel free to move this to a chat BTW.

Comment: How is a chat started?

Comment: standalone.bat - from command line or via windows web service.

Comment: Is that how you deploy applications though?

Comment: yes.  after copying the war to the deployments folder.

Comment: correction - not "windows web service", from "windows service".

Comment: the cancel message comes almost exactly one minute after starting the deployment, followed by the 60 second timeout message.

Comment: I've never seen a deployment take more than 60 seconds before. If you're on Freenode IRC try the #wildfly channel. Something seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are to ways to fix your problem.

1) go to standalone.xml (or whatever configuration you are running), find deployment-scanner and add/modify attribute deployment-timeout in seconds

2) Deploy your application as managed deployment, you can do that if you deploy trough admin console or via cli with deploy command. This way deployment will then be "managed" and will always be deployed and wont be using deployment scanner and its timeouts.

I recommend you to use deploy as managed deployment as deployment scanner is not really recommend to be used in production environments as it adds additional IO load on filesystem.
It is great for development / testing scenarios but should be avoided in production if possible.

Comment: Thanks, I had already figured out the "deployment-timeout" change.  ... so to insure the application deploys following a reboot, a windows service could be used to invoke the "deploy" command?

Comment: No, you call invoke command only when you deploy your application or lets say new version of your app, and after that application server will manage that deployment and always bring it back when it is started (unless you decide to disable or undeploy said deployment)